# How to get TextMate to auto finish your Ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, textmate

I've been following along with Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and I've noticed that his TextMate makes auto assumptions to the code, and provides suggestions and closes tags, etc., mine doesn't. How can I enable this function?

Answer (score 1):

this is mostly done with snippets, bundles and macros. There are many that are preloaded but you can customize your own. When you watch Ryan Bates "RailsCasts" you can see in the upped right what shortcuts he is pressing, helps you learn a lot.

[TextMate basics](http://projects.serenity.de/textmate/tutorials/basics/)

Answer (score -1):

I know your question is about TextMate, but Michael has a very useful page about [how to setup Sublime for Ruby/Rails](https://github.com/mhartl/rails_tutorial_sublime_text)